# how to talk to cleverbot via input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, input

i recently found [a script](https://cleverbot.io/) that uses cleverbot's api. i'm able to get a response when i enter a variable in the `ask()` function, but how can i make it so that a user can communicate with cleverbot by entering a value in an input box?

also, cleverbot's api only prints responses into the `console.log()` so i had to use the code at the bottom to transcribe the entries into the `.console` div:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var bot = new cleverbot("BIsKhtIhZdmgbOPp", "DwikyXztHk6GEG7LcvHCKfObCxYduTMP");

bot.setNick("sessionname")

bot.create(function (err, session) {
  // session is your session name, it will either be as you set it previously, or cleverbot.io will generate one for you

  // Woo, you initialized cleverbot.io.  Insert further code here
});

$('#clever').keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {

      var value = $(this).val();
      var input = value;

       if (value == input) {
          document.getElementById("input").innerHTML =
          '<p>&#62;&nbsp;' + bot.ask(input, function (err, response) {
            console.log(input);
            console.log(response);
          }); + '</p>';
       }

   }
});

if (typeof console  != "undefined")
  if (typeof console.log != 'undefined')
    console.olog = console.log;
else
  console.olog = function() {};

console.log = function(message) {
  console.olog(message);
  $('.console').append('<br>' + '<p>&#62;&nbsp;' + message + '</p>');
};
console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unilogue.github.io/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/cleverbot/cleverbot.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="console" style="width:75%;"></div>
<div id="input"></div>
<p>&#62;&nbsp;</p><input id="clever" type="text" placeholder="say something clever." />


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: to make debugging easier, you should add a word or phrase to recognize what console log you're reading so in front of every console log add something like this:
"console.log('first' + errMsg)"

Comment: i added labels to differentiate between the user's input and cleverbot's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i updated the snippet and added an if... statement to enable dialogue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var bot = new cleverbot("BIsKhtIhZdmgbOPp", "DwikyXztHk6GEG7LcvHCKfObCxYduTMP");



bot.setNick("sessionname")

bot.create(function (err, session) {
  // session is your session name, it will either be as you set it previously, or cleverbot.io will generate one for you

  // Woo, you initialized cleverbot.io.  Insert further code here
});

$('#clever').keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {

      var value = $(this).val();
      var input = value;

       if (value == input) {
          document.getElementById("input").innerHTML =
            bot.ask(input, function (err, response) {
            console.log('me > ' + input);
            console.log('cb > ' + response); // Will likely be: "Living in a lonely world"
          });
          $(this).val('');
       }

   }
});

$('html').keydown(function(e) {
 if (e.which == 118) {
    window.open('/', '_self');
}
});

if (typeof console  != "undefined")
  if (typeof console.log != 'undefined')
    console.olog = console.log;
else
  console.olog = function() {};

console.log = function(message) {
  console.olog(message);
  $('.console').append('<br>' + '<p>' + message + '</p>');
};
console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unilogue.github.io/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unilogue.github.io/js/cleverbot/cleverbot.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="console"><div id="input" style="display:none;"></div></div>
<p>me &#62;&nbsp;</p><input id="clever" type="text" placeholder="say something clever." spellcheck="false" />


</body>


</html>
```